# How to match and capture a regular expression in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I've got a regular expression like this

```
something (.*) someotherthing
```

How do I use a Regex object to match the entire expression and get the value of the capture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of what I think you are asking for:

```
Match m = Regex.Match( "something some stuff in the middle someotherthing", 
         "something (.*) someotherthing" );
if ( m.Success )
   Console.WriteLine( "groups={0}, entire match={1}, first group={2}", 
                      m.Groups.Count, m.Groups[0].Value, 
                      m.Groups[1].Value );
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you can use `$1` to get that group, you can use `$0` to get the entire expression.

This works in most regex variants (may be `\0` or `%0` or whatever), not just C#.

Similarly, the [Match.Groups property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx) should work with 0 as an argument to return the whole match, otherwise [Capture.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capture.value.aspx) looks like it contains the match.

Also worth noting, to ensure your test string matches the *entire* expression, it's generally a good idea to prefix with `^` and suffix with `$` which are zero-width position anchors for start and end of string. (Also start/end of line in multiline mode.)

Answer (score 1):

Regex.Match

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c.aspx